# ImportError: cannot import name 'accuracy_score' from 'sklearn.metrics' (unknown location)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to use sklearn evaluation metrics, but if I import package metrics and use accuracy_score I have the following problem.

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

print(accuracy_score([1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_444798/736599240.py in <module>
----> 1 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
      2 
      3 print(accuracy_score([1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]))
      4 #print(classification_report(test_generator.classes, y_pred))

ImportError: cannot import name 'accuracy_score' from 'sklearn.metrics' (unknown location)
```

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: which version of sklearn is it?

Comment: the last one... 1.0.1 @Learningisamess

Comment: what is your python version

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling Sklearn? ```pip install scikit-learn``` ?

Comment: my python version is 3.9.7 @BhavyaParikh

Comment: I have alredy done this @BimalTimilsina

Comment: Has anything "disturbed" your `PYTHONPATH`, have you created your own `sklearn` module, or are you working in an incomplete virtual environment?